# Solving Recurrence Relation with Binomial / Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I have been working on a problem and have reached an impasse.  I have a recurrence relation like this:

$n_{k} = 10n_{k-1} + 10^{k-1} - n_{k-2}$

with $n_{0} = 0$ and $n_{1} = 1$

I believe that it somehow pertains to the binomial distribution.  Any tips to lead me towards a closed form solution?  Is there a general way to 'brute force' a solution without knowing the form of the answer in advance?

Comment: Solve the eigenvalue equation.

Comment: This is an inhomogeneous second order linear recurrence with constant coefficients. Have you learn about how to solve these?

Comment: With CAS I get $n_k={{10}^{k+1}}-\frac{{{\left( 2 \sqrt{6}+5\right) }^{k}}\, \left( 49 \sqrt{6}+120\right) }{24}+\frac{{{\left( 5-2 \sqrt{6}\right) }^{k}}\, \left( 49 \sqrt{6}-120\right) }{24}$

Answer (score 1):

Difference equations are similar to differential equations. In your case, you have an obvious particular solution of the equation: $n_{p,k}=10^{k+1}$. Then you have to look for solutions to the homogeneous equation
$$
n_k-10n_{k-1}+n_{k-2}=0
$$
in the form of geometric sequence: $n_k=q^k$. When you try those, you get an equation for $q$ (the characteristic equation). In your case, you get two possible real values, hence two solutions $q_1^k$ and $q_2^k$ to your (homogeneous) equation. By linearity, the general solution of the homogeneous equation is
$$
n_k=C_1q_1^k+C_2q_2^k
$$
and then the general solution of the inhomogeneous one is
$$
n_k=C_1q_1^k+C_2q_2^k+10^{k+1}
$$
It only remains finding $C_1$ and $C_2$ using the initial conditions. You should end up with the solution given by Aleksas Domarkas.